# Visual Studio Dev Tunnels And SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr, dev-tunnels

Using the Visual Studio Dev Tunnels feature I CAN make Http(s) requests to my endpoint.
This would be my typical endpoint:

```
https://3jslj4kx-5000.uks1.devtunnels.ms/
```

I can connect to a signalr hub using localhost url but not the dev tunnel url.

```
Http://localhost:5000/myhub  works fine
```

```
https://3jslj4kx-5000.uks1.devtunnels.ms/myhub   does not work
```

Does Dev Tunnels work with signalr?

Comment: Please enable the signalr client logging feature, and share the details for us.

Comment: sample :

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/mainHub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect({
        nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: () => {
            this._errorState$.next(true);
            return 1000;
        },
        reconnectDelay: 500 // set the reconnect delay to 500ms
    })
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug).build();

Comment: Paul - Just was wondering if were you able to figure this out. Sharing something regarding this is very much appreciated. thanks a lot!

Comment: I couldn't ended using NGRok which worked with no problems.